# Why does Google Chrome slow to a crawl but when I open tabs in a different browser, it is extremely snappy?

Tags: macos, google-chrome, performance

So I currently have about 400 tabs open on Chrome (it's a lot I know) since I'm doing a lot of different work at the same time.

However at this point, my Chrome browser, starts to slow to an absolute crawl. Creating new tabs is slow. Moving between existing tabs is slow. Scrolling on any web page is very choppy. Clicking is slow. Everything is slow. It feels the same for every single tab (regardless if it's already loaded in main memory or not).

What's confusing is that I'm using MacOS on a machine with 64GB of RAM (and 10 CPU cores). According to Activity Monitor, "memory pressure" is low. Sure, "Swap Used" is high but that has made space for a lot (20GB) of fast system memory to be available (and ready to be used).

[image]

What's even more confusing, is if I open Safari, Firefox, or even a Chromium-based browser like Brave or Opera, and I start using it by creating tabs and browsing the web, those applications feel super responsive (as they should).

**So why is it that Chrome starts to slow on MacOS when there's still clearly plenty of system resources available to make it fast? Is there something on a system level I can tweak to allow Chrome to consume more resources to prevent it from slowing? I know most people don't like it when Chrome hogs RAM but in my case, I want it to take advantage of my system's hardware to prevent itself being slow.**

Comment: idk why Chrome is so poor, only that it is well-known as a memory hog. What I find odd is that you have so much swap when there's only 45GB RAM used. My Mac, 5 days uptime [usually longer but there was a security update last week] is showing 51GB used, 12GB cached, 0 bytes swap. Current use - App 42, wired 5, comp 4. I only ever expect to see 1 or 2GB swap if I've been running something with massive memory needs, not just from something like a web browser. https://i.stack.imgur.com/MReQH.png

Comment: Yeah I have no idea :( for what its worth my current uptime is 14 days and I put my computer to sleep every night so I dunno if I'm doing something to cause it use so much swap :L

Comment: I wouldn't have thought so, though my machine never sleeps, others here do & show similar memory behaviour to mine. I'd be seriously tempted to swap to Safari for a day or three & see how it compares. i don't put enough mileage on Chrome myself to really have a comparison - my inherent mistrust of all things google tends to put me off;)) so I only use it for testing.

Comment: hahaha yeah, I think I might give that a shot. Tbh I share your sentiment re Chrome and I used to use Brave as my daily driver but currently there's an [unresolved bug](https://github.com/brave/brave-browser/issues/7205) that keeps crashing PWAs so lately I've been using a Chrome a lot more :( thanks anyways for sharing your two cents :)

Comment: Welcome - & yeah, I tend to implicitly trust Apple, as their business model is to sell me hardware. Google not so much because their business model is to sell advertising.

Comment: Does it help to clear the browsing data on Chrome?

Comment: Haven't tried yet - might do it another time when I'm done using most of my open tabs since I really don't want to sign back into a tonne of things right now haha. I was hoping for this to be maybe a system issue - like maybe MacOS has this "anti-hog" feature where it starts knee-capping Chrome for using too much RAM etc.

Comment: When you are using other browser, is chrome open or not?

Comment: Yep, when I'm using other browsers like Safari, Firefox etc., my 400 Chrome tabs are still open.